# Artifactory service fails to start upon Fedora 35 reboot

Tags: artifactory, systemd

I have installed on Fedora 35 jfrog-artifactory-oss (v7.31.11-73111900.x86_64) and enabled it as a system service to start at boot. But whenever I boot up my OS, the server never starts properly. I will always need to kill the PID of the active running Artifactory process. If I then do `sudo service artifactory restart` it will bring up the server cleanly and everything is good.  How can I avoid having to do this little dance? Is there something about OS boot up that is causing Artifactory to get thrown off?

I have looked at console.log when the server is not running properly after bootup, I see some logs like:

```
2022-01-27T08:35:38.383Z [shell] [INFO] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:69] [main] - Artifactory Tomcat already started

2022-01-27T08:35:43.084Z [jfac] [WARN] [d84d2d549b318495] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:165] [pool-9-thread-2] - Retry 900 Elapsed 7.56 minutes failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
```

That shows that the server is not running properly, but doesn't give a clear idea of what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

2 things to check,

- How is the artifactory.service file in the systemd directory
- Whenever the OS is rebooted, what is the error seen in the logs, check all the logs.

Hint: From the warning shared, it seems that Router service is not able to start when OS is rebooted, so whenever OS is rebooted and issue comes up check the router-service.log for any errors/warnings.

Comment: ```2022-01-27T08:38:49.625Z [jfrou] [ERROR] [ ] [server_configuration.go:92    ] [main                ] - error configuring load balancer for frontend jfac_01ft5r4hvbpph00pcg38ze041y-0-jfac_01ft5r4hvbpph00pcg38ze041y-foo_localdomain-external: error parsing server URL http://[fe80::3dac:df5c:887b:8c70%wlan0]:8082: parse "http://[fe80::3dac:df5c:887b:8c70%wlan0]:8082": invalid URL escape "%wl". Skipping frontend jfac_01ft5r4hvbpph00pcg38ze041y-0-jfac_01ft5r4hvbpph00pcg38ze041y-foo_localdomain-external...
```

Comment: This was from router-traefik.log. Get the same error though on successful restart. So may not be related to the root cause.

Comment: check errors when there is no successful restart